# Runtime Error 1004 Method Intersect' of object _Global failed

Tags: excel, vba, events, excel-2007

I want to speed up some data entry. I found code online which worked until I applied the same code to a few more sheets. Now I get

> Runtime Error '1004':, Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed

Here is the basic version. It varies on different sheets.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 5
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now + 365
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("E:E"), Target)
    xOffsetColumn = 4
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Rng In WorkRng
            If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now + 365
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            Else
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This seems to be the problem:

```
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), Target)
```

Comment: I'd use `Me` instead of `Application.ActiveSheet` tbh.

Comment: You could also use the [`DateAdd` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) instead of adding 365 days to `Now` - won't cause errors when there's a leap year.

Comment: not to worried on the date thing atm. just getting the code to work on multiple pages is my target

Comment: [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) will fail if "one or more ranges from a different worksheet are specified". Since you're using the Worksheet_Change event, `Target` should always be on the `ActiveSheet` - however, `Me` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to specify which application the intersect was coming from:

```
Public Function IsInRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
    Dim Excel As Application, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Range1.Parent
    Set wb = ws.Parent
    Set Excel = wb.Application
    If Range1.Parent Is Range2.Parent Then
        IsInRange = Not (Excel.Intersect(Range1, Range2) Is Nothing)
    Else
        IsInRange = False
    End If
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set Excel = Nothing
End Function
```